# Where can I see my downloads history in Internet Explorer 10?

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, download, history

Is there any database or file that saves all the downloads history in Internet Explorer 10?
Something like index.dat that contains all the visits history in Internet Explorer or like downloads.sqlite in Firefox that contains all the downloads history from Firefox.

Comment: In Internet Explorer 11, you can access it by pressing CTRL-J. Not sure if this already worked in 10.

Comment: They can also be found in %LocalAppData%\Microsoft\Windows\History (pick a week and look in the Computer folder.)